# git push heroku master does not push java maven target/dependency directory to heroku

Tags: java, git, heroku, dependencies

When I do a `git push heroku master` on my java application, it does not push the "target/dependency" directory to heroku.

I followed the example for my application and the Procfile shows `web:    java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* HelloWorld` which seems to imply that the target/dependency directory can be there.

My build creates everything correctly and `foreman` executes the application correctly but when I push to heroku, the dependency directory is missing and the application fails to execute because those dependencies are missing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your `target/dependency` directory is committed to your git repository before you push.

Use the `git status` command to see if it is committed.

Comment: The target directory is not committed. I think what I am looking for is to add a local repository to the POM. Heroku appears to describes that here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies.